# How to merge 2 datasets with Python / Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two pandas datasets:

```
    Name        A   B
1   Michael     1   2
2   Peter       3   4
```

and

```
    Name        C   D
1   Peter       8   9
2   John        5   6
```

How can I merge these datasets to get the following result:

```
    Name        A   B   C   D
1   Michael     1   2   -   -
2   Peter       3   4   8   9
3   John        -   -   5   6
```

The value for "-" should either be 0 or NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to perform an [outer join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra):

```
df1.merge(df2, on = 'Name', how = "outer")

#      Name    A    B    C    D
#0  Michael  1.0  2.0  NaN  NaN
#1    Peter  3.0  4.0  8.0  9.0
#2     John  NaN  NaN  5.0  6.0
```